# mouseMoveEvent() while cursor is on button

Tags: python, pyqt

I have to activate some function, when the cursor is moving. So, I used **self.setMouseTracking(True)** in MainWidget. But in this way **mouseMoveEvent()** works only when there is an empty form under cursor. I tried to create another widget over main, but it doesnt work at all.

```
class ClickButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, window):
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.clickers = [ClickButton('OK', self) for i in range(8)]

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        for e in self.clickers:
            e.run()
```

Whats to do?

Comment: you could provide a [mcve], from what I understand you have a window where there are several widgets like QPushButton, QLineEdit, etc and then you want to get the position even when there is the button under the mouse. I am right?

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Comment: Yes or no??????

Comment: Im calling a function which moves the buttons. But does it matters?

Comment: Explain better, I think you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) if you want to move the buttons with mouseMoveEvent. What is your ultimate goal: move the buttons or track the mouse?

Comment: The buttons move perfectly, while cursor doesnt touch them, but they stop, when the cursor is moving ON one of them, because of some filter in mouseMoveEvent() function.

Comment: You say in the comments on movement of buttons but in your question does not say anything about it, do not you think that confuses? In your question you must clearly indicate what you want, not only the possible solution that nobody guarantees that works for what until now will assume that you want to call some function while the mouse is on the button (assume that the function that is called works correctly)

Comment: Because moving buttons is not the problem. I am sure that I shouldnt post all the code here, when I need to find a short solution in a small piece of it.

Comment: try with my second solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect the position of the mouse even when the mouse is on top of a child, a possible option is to use an event filter.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        w_ = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay_w = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w_)
        for c in (QtWidgets.QPushButton(), QtWidgets.QLineEdit()):
            lay_w.addWidget(c)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for w in (QtWidgets.QPushButton(), QtWidgets.QLineEdit(), QtWidgets.QTextEdit(), w_):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        for ws in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget) + [self]:
            ws.setMouseTracking(True)
            ws.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            p_respect_to_window = self.mapFromGlobal(obj.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
            print(p_respect_to_window)
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

On the other hand if you only want to do it in only one type of custom widget it is better to overwrite the mouseMoveEvent method of the custom widget:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ClickButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(ClickButton, self).__init__(text=text, parent=parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.run()
        super(ClickButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def run(self):
        print("call to run function in button{} and time: {}".format(self.text(), 
            QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()))

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(10):
            w = ClickButton(str(i), self)
            lay.addWidget(w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```